# Joda time invalid format

Tags: android, jodatime

there's an error when I try to execute this code with Joda time:

```
// yyyy-mm-dd, also tried 17-Feb-2013
String input = "2013-02-17";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(input);

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvShow);
tv.setText("HERE >>> " + dt.toString());
```

any ideas?

logcat says:

```
03-18 16:58:14.919: W/System.err(8259): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2013-02-17" is malformed at "13-02-17"
03-18 16:58:14.919: W/System.err(8259):     at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:871)
03-18 16:58:14.919: W/System.err(8259):     at com.example.dateformatter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
03-18 16:58:14.919: W/System.err(8259):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
03-18 16:58:14.919: W/System.err(8259):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
03-18 16:58:14.919: W/System.err(8259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
03-18 16:58:14.919: W/System.err(8259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
03-18 16:58:14.919: W/System.err(8259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-18 16:58:14.919: W/System.err(8259):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
03-18 16:58:14.927: W/System.err(8259):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 16:58:14.927: W/System.err(8259):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-18 16:58:14.927: W/System.err(8259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
03-18 16:58:14.927: W/System.err(8259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 16:58:14.927: W/System.err(8259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-18 16:58:14.927: W/System.err(8259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
03-18 16:58:14.927: W/System.err(8259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
03-18 16:58:14.927: W/System.err(8259):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 16:58:14.950: D/KeyguardViewMediator(357): setHidden false
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with either Android or Eclipse, by the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've asked it to *parse* "2013-02-17" as if it were in the format "dd/MM/yyyy", which it's clearly not.

You need to specify `yyyy-MM-dd` as the pattern:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Or if you need `dd/MM/yyyy` as the pattern, you need to provide it text of that form, e.g.

```
String input = "17/02/2013";
```

Either way, the data you're providing has to match the format you're specifying. That's the whole point of specifying the format, after all.

See the docs for [`DateTimeFormat`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) for what the various letters in the format pattern mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code u input wrong date format.

```
String input = "17/02/2013";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(input);
```

Comment: That's going to fail as well, because "-" isn't the same as "/".

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for notify my mistake now im update my answer and apologies for small mistake!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are not suppose to make a confusion in the format

**Option 1**

String input = "`2013-02-17`";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("`yyyy-MM-dd`");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(input);

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvShow);
tv.setText("HERE >>> " + dt.toString());

**Option 2**

String input = "`17/02/2013`";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("`dd/MM/yyyy`");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(input);

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvShow);
tv.setText("HERE >>> " + dt.toString());